# Pop values into sublist by index

Tags: python, list

How could I pop values into sublists based on given indexes.

```
lst = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10,11,12]]
indexes = 0 , 2, 3
```

Result looking for:

```
result = [[2, 5, 6] , [7, 11, 12]]
```

Comment: I don't see what the relationship between the input and the desired output is, or what you mean by "pop values into sublists". You're going to need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lst = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
indexes = [0, 2, 3]
res = []
for x in lst:
    ls = []
    for xi, xy in enumerate(x):
        if xi not in indexes:
            ls.append(xy)
    res.append(ls)

print(res)
```

Output

```
[[2, 5, 6], [8, 11, 12]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `list` comprehension:

```
print([[v for i, v in enumerate(x) if i not in indexes] for x in lst])
```

Output:

```
[[2, 5, 6], [8, 11, 12]]
```

As the OP mentioned, he wants a way with using a loop, so use this:

```
l = []
for x in lst:
    it = []
    for i, v in enumerate(x):
        if i not in indexes:
            it.append(v)
    l.append(it)
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[[2, 5, 6], [8, 11, 12]]
```

Comment: That doesn't produce the desired output, though. I have no idea what the question is asking for.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Edited my answer, I get what he means now, he want the ones where the index is **not** in `indexes`

Comment: That still doesn't produce the desired output. (Also, the brackets are mismatched.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica That's true, anyway I keep the answer here, this might still answer the OP's question, it might be that he accidentally put the wrong `lst`

Comment: Looks like OP made a typo in the expected output. This answer looks good to me.

Comment: @PrinceOfCreation That's possible.

Comment: @FernandoRodríguez I will edit